# Using Regular Expression to find exact length match multiple times

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression to find groups of exactly 8 numbers in a row. The closest I have gotten is:

```
 [0-9]{8}
```

but it's not exactly what I need. If I had a number that was 9 long it will match the first 8 but I want it to ignore it if it's longer or shorter than 8.

Here are some examples

```
1234567890 <- no match, it's longer than 8
12345678 <- match: "12345678"
1234567809876543 <- match 1: "12345678", match 2: "09876543" (two groups of 8)
,,111-11-1234,12345678, <- match: "12345678"
```

To summarize, for every group of exactly 8 numbers make a match.

I'm working with some results of OCR (Optical Character Recognition) and I have to work with the shortcomings of the results so my input can be varied as in the examples above.

Here is some use case data: http://pastebin.com/uijF9K9n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex in .NET:

```
(?<=^|\D|(?:\d{8})+)\d{8}(?=$|\D|(?:\d{8})+)
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5e%7c%5cD%7c(%3f%3a%5cd%7b8%7d)%2b)%5cd%7b8%7d(%3f%3d%24%7c%5cD%7c(%3f%3a%5cd%7b8%7d)%2b)&i=1234567890+%3c-+no+match%2c+it%27s+longer+than+8%0d%0a12345678%0d%0a1234567809876543%0d%0a%2c%2c111-11-1234%2c12345678%2c%0d%0a123456780987654309876543)

It is based on variable-width lookbehind and a lookahead.

Regex breakdown:

- `(?<=^|\D|(?:\d{8})+)` - only if at the string start (`^`), or preceded with not a digit (`\D`) or 1 or more sequences of 8 digits (`(?:\d{8})+`)...
- `\d{8}` - match 8 digits that are followed by...
- `(?=$|\D|(?:\d{8})+)` - either end of string (`$`) or not a digit (`\D`) or 1 or more sequences of 8 digits (`(?:\d{8})+`).

**IMPORTANT**:

If I got a downvote for the "extra" complexity compared with another answer, note **our solutions are different**: [my regex matches 8-digit number in `ID12345678`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5e%7c%5cD%7c(%3f%3a%5cd%7b8%7d)%2b)%5cd%7b8%7d(%3f%3d%24%7c%5cD%7c(%3f%3a%5cd%7b8%7d)%2b)&i=ID12345678%0d%0a), and [the other one does not](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3a%5cb%7c%5cG)%5cd%7b8%7d(%3f%3d(%3f%3a%5cd%7b8%7d)*%5cb)&i=ID12345678%0d%0a) due to the word boundary.

Comment: This looks good. Thank you! I suppose you say .NET because Lookbehind is not supported in Javascript?

Comment: Variable lookbehind is supported in few regex implementations: 1) .NET, 2) JGSoft, 3) Python PyPi regex module. In JS, there is no lookbehind support at all. :( I have added some explanations.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please explain. If you want to play with down arrows, [here is a good link](https://www.google.pl/search?q=down+arrow&biw=1745&bih=868&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CB0QsARqFQoTCIKK2bG3l8kCFQVrFAodE28M3w).

Comment: If I got a downvote for the "extra" complexity compared with another answer, note **our solutions are different**: [my regex matches 8-digit number in `ID12345678`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5e%7c%5cD%7c(%3f%3a%5cd%7b8%7d)%2b)%5cd%7b8%7d(%3f%3d%24%7c%5cD%7c(%3f%3a%5cd%7b8%7d)%2b)&i=ID12345678%0d%0a), and [the other one does not](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3a%5cb%7c%5cG)%5cd%7b8%7d(%3f%3d(%3f%3a%5cd%7b8%7d)*%5cb)&i=ID12345678%0d%0a) due to the word boundary.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter. Our solutions are also different that yours matches two 8s in `12345678123456789` whereas mine doesn't. Not sure what's exact requirement. However I also appreciate your approach +1

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this regex

```
(?:\b|\G)\d{8}(?=(?:\d{8})*\b)
```

- `(?:\b|\G)`  `\b` match a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `|` or `\G` continue where [last match attempt ended](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Contiguous)
- `\d{8}` matches 8 [digits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#DigitCharacter) `[0-9]` followed by a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=`... to check
- `(?:\d{8})*\b` if followed by any amount of {8 digits} until another word boundary

It will match {8 digits} or out of a sequence of such if between two word boundaries.

[See demo at regexstorm](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3A%5Cb%7C%5CG)%5Cd%7B8%7D(%3F%3D(%3F%3A%5Cd%7B8%7D)*%5Cb)&i=1234567890%20%3C-%20no%20match%2C%20it%27s%20longer%20than%208%0D%0A12345678%20%3C-%20match%3A%20%2212345678%22%0D%0A1234567809876543%20%3C-%20match%201%3A%20%2212345678%22%2C%20match%202%3A%20%2209876543%22%20(two%20groups%20of%208)%0D%0A%2C%2C111-11-1234%2C12345678%2C%20%3C-%20match%3A%20%2212345678%22%0D%0A12345678%20123456789%201234567812345678%2012345678123456789)

Comment: I also thought about using `\G`, but since the requirement was not clear I decided to use a custom boundary with lookarounds and avoid `\b` that sometimes is too restrictive.

Comment: @Pulseczar If it's a requirement to also match the digits enclosed in letters like `a12345678b` just replace `\b` with lookarounds [like this](http://goo.gl/vjX4l2) `(?:(?<!\d)|\G)\d{8}(?=(?:\d{8})*(?!\d))`

Answer (score 0):

\b[0-9]{8}\b this will give you what you want
For more details check this out
http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html

Comment: This isn't working for 2 groups of 8 with no boundary in between them, like this: 1234567812345678. [http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5b0-9%5d%7b8%7d%5cb&i=1234567890+%3c-+no+match%2c+it%27s+longer+than+8%0d%0a12345678%0d%0a1234567809876543%0d%0a%2c%2c111-11-1234%2c12345678%2c%0d%0a123456780987654309876543](regex demo)

Comment: (?:(\b\d{8})(\d{8}\b)|(\b\d{8}\b)) Try this